# 555 Timer Monostable Circuit Triggered When Circuit is Powerd

Tags: 555

My monostable 555 timer circuit (like the one seen below from [Electronic Tutorials](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_timer.html)) behaves as it should in a steady a steady-state environment.

However, the 555 timer is also undesirably triggered when the circuit is initially powered.

How can I prevent this unwanted startup activation?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of simply tying the reset input directly to Vcc, add an R-C time delay that is significantly longer than the risetime of the supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I just found the schematic below from the article "[Power-Up Reset For 555 Timers](http://home.cogeco.ca/~rpaisley4/LM555.html)" that eliminated the startup activation.

[image]